# How to print all the values with 'id':

Tags: python

Below is a list of things.. lol sorry quite new at python.. so this is a list?

Anyway, I want to print all the values of the key 'id' i.e. the first value is 'xxxx@gmail.com'

I have looked for a while and can't seem to find a way to do that.

```
list_entry = {'kind': 'calendar#calendarList', 'etag': '"p328cl9tbhinuc0g"', 'nextSyncToken': 'CJDKp6uMr-YCEhZwZXRlcmNoaWVuODJAZ21haWwuY29t', 'items': [{'kind': 'calendar#calendarListEntry', 'etag': '"1576118870730000"', 'id': 'xxxx@gmail.com', 'summary': 'peterchien82@gmail.com', 'timeZone': 'Asia/Taipei', 'colorId': '18', 'backgroundColor': '#b99aff', 'foregroundColor': '#000000', 'selected': True, 'accessRole': 'owner', 'defaultReminders': [{'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 2}, {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 30}], 'notificationSettings': {'notifications': [{'type': 'eventCreation', 'method': 'email'}, {'type': 'eventChange', 'method': 'email'}, {'type': 'eventCancellation', 'method': 'email'}]}, 'primary': True, 'conferenceProperties': {'allowedConferenceSolutionTypes': ['eventHangout']}}, {'kind': 'calendar#calendarListEntry', 'etag': '"1567066298066000"', 'id': 'addressbook#contacts@group.v.calendar.google.com', 'summary': 'Contacts', 'timeZone': 'Asia/Taipei', 'summaryOverride': 'Contacts', 'colorId': '17', 'backgroundColor': '#9a9cff', 'foregroundColor': '#000000', 'selected': True, 'accessRole': 'reader', 'defaultReminders': [], 'conferenceProperties': {'allowedConferenceSolutionTypes': ['eventHangout']}}, {'kind': 'calendar#calendarListEntry', 'etag': '"1567066298066000"', 'id': 'en.canadian#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com', 'summary': 'Holidays in Canada', 'timeZone': 'Asia/Taipei', 'summaryOverride': 'Holidays in Canada', 'colorId': '7', 'backgroundColor': '#42d692', 'foregroundColor': '#000000', 'selected': True, 'accessRole': 'reader', 'defaultReminders': [], 'conferenceProperties': {'allowedConferenceSolutionTypes': ['eventHangout']}}]}
```

Comment: This is a dictionary, not a list.

Comment: Please look at **any** Python tutorial on dictionaries and "if statement"s.

Comment: The main object is a dictionary. The value of the `items` element in the dictionary is a list of dictionaries.

Comment: You can use a `for` loop to process the elements of the list, and print the `id` element of each dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex:

```
import re
pat=r"id'[:]\s\'(.*?)\'"

re.findall(pat, str(list_entry))
```

output:

```
['xxxx@gmail.com',
 'addressbook#contacts@group.v.calendar.google.com',
 'en.canadian#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com']
```

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a complex dictionary with some lists and dictionaries further embedded in it. To access the information you are looking for, you can use for example the following:

```
for i in list_entry['items']: print(i['id'])
```

This for-loop goes over the list of dictionaries associated with the key `'items'`. Each of these dictionaries in turn has a key `'id'`, which has associated with it the information you are looking for. The output of this code looks like this:

```
xxxx@gmail.com
addressbook#contacts@group.v.calendar.google.com
en.canadian#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com
```

You could also save these emails in one variable using list comprehension:

```
emails = [i['id'] for i in list_entry['items']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below:

```py
list_entry = {'kind': 'calendar#calendarList', 'etag': '"p328cl9tbhinuc0g"', 'nextSyncToken': 'CJDKp6uMr-YCEhZwZXRlcmNoaWVuODJAZ21haWwuY29t', 'items': [{'kind': 'calendar#calendarListEntry', 'etag': '"1576118870730000"', 'id': 'xxxx@gmail.com', 'summary': 'peterchien82@gmail.com', 'timeZone': 'Asia/Taipei', 'colorId': '18', 'backgroundColor': '#b99aff', 'foregroundColor': '#000000', 'selected': True, 'accessRole': 'owner', 'defaultReminders': [{'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 2}, {'method': 'popup', 'minutes': 30}], 'notificationSettings': {'notifications': [{'type': 'eventCreation', 'method': 'email'}, {'type': 'eventChange', 'method': 'email'}, {'type': 'eventCancellation', 'method': 'email'}]}, 'primary': True, 'conferenceProperties': {'allowedConferenceSolutionTypes': ['eventHangout']}}, {'kind': 'calendar#calendarListEntry', 'etag': '"1567066298066000"', 'id': 'addressbook#contacts@group.v.calendar.google.com', 'summary': 'Contacts', 'timeZone': 'Asia/Taipei', 'summaryOverride': 'Contacts', 'colorId': '17', 'backgroundColor': '#9a9cff', 'foregroundColor': '#000000', 'selected': True, 'accessRole': 'reader', 'defaultReminders': [], 'conferenceProperties': {'allowedConferenceSolutionTypes': ['eventHangout']}}, {'kind': 'calendar#calendarListEntry', 'etag': '"1567066298066000"', 'id': 'en.canadian#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com', 'summary': 'Holidays in Canada', 'timeZone': 'Asia/Taipei', 'summaryOverride': 'Holidays in Canada', 'colorId': '7', 'backgroundColor': '#42d692', 'foregroundColor': '#000000', 'selected': True, 'accessRole': 'reader', 'defaultReminders': [], 'conferenceProperties': {'allowedConferenceSolutionTypes': ['eventHangout']}}]}

def find_id(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k in d:
            if k == 'id':
                print(d[k])
            foo(d[k])
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for i in d:
            foo(i)

find_id(list_entry)
```

```
xxxx@gmail.com
addressbook#contacts@group.v.calendar.google.com
en.canadian#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com
```